# PhoneGap Cordova > 3.1.0 inAppBrowser not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm using cordova 3.3 with InAppBrowser plugin. When i call

```
ref = window.open('http://www.google.de', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

in my onDeviceReady ready function all is fine.

But i have a second function, i called it after onDeviceReady is finished.

```
function LinkDropBox() {
  ref = window.open('http://www.google.de', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

error console told me:
uncaught typeerror property 'open' of [object global] object is not a function

Any ideas to fix it?

i already tried

```
typeof window.open
```

in LinkDropBox and onDeviceReady function

- In onDeviceReady it returns "function"
- in LinkDropBox  it returns "string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you are overwriting window.open by forgetting the `var` keyword in front of a local variable, e.g.

```
function doSomething() {
  open = "hello world";
}
```

instead of

```
function doSomething() {
  var open = "hello world";
}
```

Can you check your code for this issue?

Comment: perfect answer. i used jquery-i18n-properties plugin for translation and defined in Messages.properties a open var ....